# Image rendering correctly as html but not in email template

Tags: javascript, html, email-templates

I am new to html & javascript and current working on an email template related task. The template is abcd.template but inside the code is in html format. I am trying to embed an image from a javascript file EncodedImage.js where the 64 bit encoded image is stored in a variable Image.encoding. Please find my sample code below:

```
    <html>
               <head> 
                  <script type="text/javascript" 
                    src="./EncodedImage.js">
                </script>
               </head> 
               <body> 
                  <script>
                    function getImagePath() {
                      return Image.encoding;
                }
                  </script> 
                  <img src onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src=getImagePath();">  
               </body>
            </html>
```

The image looks fine when I test by changing .template extension to .html and launch in a browser. The issue is not with 64 bit encoded image. But when I actually test the email triggering functionality where the template is consumed, the image is not getting rendered. The image section in the email just shows blank, everything else is rendered correctly.  What could be the reason for this? I suspect the template file is unable to find EncodedImage.js placed in same location as template file on the server, but this is just a shot in the dark. Please provide guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the image but in fact the way you included your js file in the HTML.

Problem :

an email will just render the mail's HTML in a small frame.
and at that time, when the HTML try to load the HTML file : **EncodedImage.js** from the path : **./** it'll actually try to find the js file in the **[www.your-email-provider.com/](http://www.your-email-provider.com/)** registry and your js code is in your local system.  Hence there won't be js added to your HTML file.

Hence no image loading.

Solutions :
Add all the javascript code in the **script** tag and add that tag inside ( at the end ) of the **body** tag. Or

Upload your javascript code to any cloud and get the link of the uploaded javascript file. ( like AWS S3, CloudFront ) or build your own CDN ( using jsDelivr etc )